# SendAsync in Rebus

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, rebus

We are using Rebus over Azure Service Bus. Is there any way to perform sending messages in an asynchronous way? I haven't managed to find anything like SendAsync in Rebus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there's no way to `bus.SendAsync`/`bus.PublishAsync` etc. with Rebus - mostly because the `async`/`await` support is pretty new, and you're the first to ask for it :)

There's no reason really why Rebus should not support it, so I've [created an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/291) for the feature, which you might want to keep an eye on if you're interested in having awaitable send operations :)

Comment: in case you're still interested in having this feature, I can tell you that Rebus2 (which will soon be available:)) is `async` by default